# Why do I need to submit twice for my mapped function to display the updated state after updating the array content?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch-api

I am trying to display an img for the current value in the array item, but onload, when I submit my value, the image does not display. I submit twice to display the value. When changing the value and pressing submit, the div does not update the content with new value, but repeats the old one. After submitting again, the div is updated with new value.

```jsx
export default function Ingredients() {
  const [form, setForm] = useState("");
  const [theimg, setheimg] = useState({
    name: "",
    url: "",
    id: "",
  });
  const [imgArr, setImgArr] = useState([]);

  function handleChange(e) {
    setForm(e.target.value);
  }

  function getImg() {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "29a63a7413msh8378b61a2e11cf3p192e62jsn53d83f1651fe",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "edamam-food-and-grocery-database.p.rapidapi.com",
      },
    };
    fetch(
      `https://edamam-food-and-grocery-database.p.rapidapi.com/parser?ingr=${form}`,
      options
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) =>
        setheimg((prevImg) => ({
          ...prevImg,
          name: form,
          url: response.parsed[0].food.image,
          id: Math.random(),
        }))
      )
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }

  const thingsElements = imgArr.map((thing) => (
    <div key={thing.id}>
      <img src={thing.url} />
      <p>{thing.name}</p>
    </div>
  ));

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar page="/" />
      <Heading heading="Ingredients" info="Search by etc" />
      <Form
        label="Search Ingredients..."
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={form.value}
        imgsrc={theimg}
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          getImg();
          setImgArr((oldArray) => {
            return [...oldArray, theimg];
          });
        }}
      >
        Search
      </button>
      {thingsElements}
    </>
  );
}
```

```jsx
const Form = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <label>
        {props.label}
        <input value={props.value} onChange={props.onChange} />
      </label>
    </>
  );
};
export default Form;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your click handler, you aren't waiting for `getImg()` to complete before adding `theimg` to the array.

Try something like this instead

```js
const getImg = async () => {
  const params = new URLSearchParams({ ingr: form });
  const res = await fetch(`https://example.com/parser?${params}`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "X-RapidAPI-Key": "<api-key>",
      "X-RapidAPI-Host": "<host>",
    },
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw res;
  }

  const data = await response.json();
  return {
    name: form,
    url: data.parsed[0].food.image,
    id: Math.random(), // recommend Date.now() instead
  };
};

const clickHandler = async () => {
  try {
    const newImg = await getImg(); // wait for getImg() to resolve
    settheimg(newImg); // set img state
    setImgArr((prev) => [...prev, newImg]); // add it to the array
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

and in your `<button>`...

```html
<button onClick={clickHandler}>Search</button>
```

Comment: You are amazing, thank you very much for the solution. I really appreciate the time you spent helping me out!